# DATEADD() does not add to Hours/Minutes/Seconds in Tableau

Tags: date, tableau-api

Found that I am unable to add hours, minutes or seconds to date in Tableau Desktop.
Tried :

```
DateADD('second', 1, #1970-01-01#) gives 1/1/1970 00:00:00  (expected : 1/1/1970 00:00:01)
```

```
DateADD('minute', 1, #1970-01-01#) gives 1/1/1970 00:00:00  (expected : 1/1/1970 00:01:00)
```

```
    DateADD('hour', 1, #1970-01-01 00:00:00#) gives 1/1/1970 00:00:00 (expected :1/1/1970 01:00:00)
```

But adding date works as expected

```
DateADD('day', 1, #1970-01-01 00:00:00#) gives 1/2/1970 00:00:00
```

Since I am using epoch date in seconds, the time part is not correctly calculated. The date part is getting calculated correctly. No matter how many seconds/minutes/hours I add, only if there is a change in date part, the change is reflected.

Am I going wrong anywhere? How can I display the correct time?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Date and DateTime are different data types. One includes time of day also, the other doesn’t.  The icons for the data types are a calendar and a calendar + a watch respectively. Make sure you are using the right data types for your task.

Comment: Yes, that may be a problem.  `Date` and `Datetime` are two different datatypes in Tableau.

Comment: In my case, the date to be added is epoch. which is a number. The calculated field is a Date and Time that does not add hours minutes or seconds.

Comment: @tentner, in your screenshots the datatype shown is `Abc`, try to fix that issue

Comment: @AnilGoyal That is not an error. The trailing Abc is there in ur screenshot also.

Comment: Ok, that is due to empty measure values therein.

Comment: @tentner, please see my edited answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see why it is not working in your case.  It is working perfectly, in mine.

I added two calc fields one having 1 hour addition and another 20 minutes addition.  See the result.

[image]

EDIT: I got the error in your viz.  Instead of formatting the calculated field as date-time, just click the pill, select 'exact date' instead of 'day' **(in your view it is clear you're showing *day of calculated field* instead of *calculated field*)** click again and select discreet.  And your problem should be solved.

[image]

You're doing this instead

[image]